# I am trying to solve this equation in Mathematica, but I am not getting the correct answer

Tags: numerical-integration, special-functions

I am considering the following integral: $$F_y=4\pi\varepsilon\mu_0 M^2 R^2\int_\infty^0\frac{J_1\left(\tfrac{r q}{R}\right)}{q}J_1^2(q)\sinh^2\left(\frac{q t}{2R}\right)e^{-\tfrac{q s}{R}}\,\mathrm d q$$ where $J_1(z)$ is the Bessel function of the first kind of order 1, `BesselJ[1, z]`.

When I try to integrate for $r=0$ and $s=0$ I get zero as the answer. But the paper I am following gives value as 24.94 N. ($\varepsilon$ is 1.)

```
μ = 4*Pi*10^-7;
M = 0.891*10^6;
R = 5*10^-3;
s = 0;
t = 5*10^-3;
r = 0;
     NIntegrate[
     4 Pi μ M^2 R^2*( ((BesselJ[1, (r q/R)])/q)*(BesselJ[1, q]^2)*
        Exp[-(q s/R)]*Sinh[(q t/(2 R))]^2), {q, Infinity, 0}, 
     AccuracyGoal -> 32]
```

This integral came from this [paper](https://doi.org/10.1088/0964-1726/24/4/045042) (also available [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/273793936_Finite_element_modeling_of_nonlinear_piezoelectric_energy_harvesters_with_magnetic_interaction)), in particular page 5.

Comment: `But the paper I am following gives value as 24.94 N` what is `N`? I see no `N` anywhere.

Comment: Look at the result of  `Plot[4 Pi \[Mu] M^2 R^2*(((BesselJ[1, (r q/R)])/q)*(BesselJ[1, q]^2)*
    Exp[-(q s/R)]*Sinh[(q t/(2 R))]^2), {q, 0, 3}, PlotStyle -> Thick]`.

Comment: You have a `BesselJ[1, 0]` because of `r=0`.

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. If you are just starting out, there are great online resources such as the Fast Introduction for [Math](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-math-students/en/)  
 students as well as the introductory [book](https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/) written by the inventor. Please respond to the comments so that you can receive additional help. Thanks.

Comment: @Nasser N is unit of force Fy(Newton).

Comment: @b.gates.you.know.what Yes that is what I thought of. And BesselJ[1,0] is 0.

Comment: @Steverock And "the paper you're following" considers the same integral (including `BesselJ[1,0]` )?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann here is the paper. I am getting the same graph but in one of paragraph they are trying to find contact force by substituting r=0 and s=0.


https://www.researchgate.net/publication/273793936_Finite_element_modeling_of_nonlinear_piezoelectric_energy_harvesters_with_magnetic_interaction

Comment: @Steverock Thanks, figure 4b shows variing values of `r`, especially for `r==0` `force==0`

Comment: @UlrichNeumann yes but that graph is for s=10mm. With s=0, r=0 we get the contact force as per the paper(PAGE 5). They have mentioned that substituting r=0 and s=0 we get 24.64N. That is where I am confused. Thank you for response

Comment: @Steverock Setting s=10 (or .01, don't know the units) doesn't reproduce figure 4g!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann so what am I doing wrong here? Is my code wrong? Thank you again for response.

Comment: @Steverock The coding is ok I think. Perhaps an error in the paper? I'm unsure about the units.